# How to use the same session during entire OAuth authentication process?

Tags: spring, session, oauth-2.0, zapier

I have a Spring application that we're trying to integrate with Zapier using their OAuth V2 process (described here: https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/oauth-v2/). The process basically happens in two parts:

1. Zapier does a GET request to our `authorization_url`, user logs in if necessary, and clicks "Confirm" to authorize Zapier to connect. We generate a `code` token, and redirect to their `redirect_uri` with it.
2. Zapier does a POST request to our `access_token_url` with the `code` we gave and some other data, expecting an `access_token` back.

The problem we're experiencing is that the request for #2 comes in as a brand new request, and so our app redirects that request to our login page, which breaks the whole thing cause it's not what Zapier expects to get back.

Does anyone know how to get Zapier to re-use the session it was using for part 1 for part 2 as well? I noticed that if a user is already logged in and tries to start the authentication process (part 1), they are not asked (redirected) to login, but the second call from Zapier always comes in without any session info and thus is redirected to login.

Is this some configuration issue? I searched around online and wasn't able to find much useful info on this as if it should "just work" using the same session for the whole process.